# Deny sql queries in string argument for a clish command

Tags: clish

If possible I would like to have clish to rewrite any arguments  that are not safe to inject in an sql query. Similar to doing for example `mysql_real_escape_string` in php.

From clish we are calling bashscripts that sometimes injects the arguments into sql queries. Offcourse we should check/rewrite the argument in the bash-script's, but making clish rewrite the query  would be an extra security in case that are missed/forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a wrapper that executes all clish commands. 
It will look like this in the command xml syntax:

```
   <ACTION>execWrap aCommandToExecute ${someArgument}</ACTION>
```

execWrap will execute "aCommandToExecute" with all folowing arguments passed to it  after verifying that the arguments are safe.

However, I will not mark the question as solved as it would be prefered to do this inside clish.